# How to customize the data retrieved by a REST call?

Tags: 7, services

I've enabled the [REST server](http://drupal.org/project/services) (plus services) and can retrieve user profile data at www.example.com/endpoint/user/123

How can I customize the data that's being retrieve? I want to not include the email address and add a couple of other fields.

When I make a login request at www.example.com/endpoint/user/login I would like to have those additional fields included as well.

Comment: how you enable REST server module while its not available or Drupal 7? "the Drupal 7 port of the REST Server is already packaged with the Services module"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to define your Resource, take a look at files in site/all/module/services/resources, you can find some examples, but for simplicity I will take you and example:

endpoint_user moduel:

endpoint_user.info file:

```
name = endpoint_user
description = endpoint_user
core = 7.x
```

endpoint_user.module file:

```
<?php
function endpoint_user_services_resources() {
  $endpoint_user_resource = array(
      'endpoint_user' => array(
          'retrieve' => array(
              'callback' => '_endpoint_user_resource_retrieve',
              'args' => array(
                  array(
                      'name' => 'uid',
                      'optional' => FALSE,
                      'source' => array('path' => 0),
                      'type' => 'int',
                      'description' => 'The uid of the endpoint_user to get',
                  ),
              ),
              'access callback' => '_endpoint_user_resource_access',
              'access arguments' => array('view'),
              'access arguments append' => TRUE,
          ),
      ),
  );
  return $endpoint_user_resource;
}

function _endpoint_user_resource_access($op = 'view', $args = array()) {
  return TRUE;
}

function _endpoint_user_resource_retrieve($uid) {
  $endpoint_user = user_load($uid);
  $endpoint_user->custom_field = 'Mohammad Ali Akbari';
  if ($endpoint_user) {
    $uri = entity_uri('user', $endpoint_user);
    $endpoint_user->path = url($uri['path'], array('absolute' => TRUE));
    // Unset uri as it has complete entity and this
    // cause never ending recursion in rendering.
    unset($endpoint_user->uri);
  }
  return $endpoint_user;
}
```

then create new Service in `admin/structure/services` and select endpoint_user.

open your browser and go to your service URL, like endpoint/endpoint_user/1

you will see:

```
<custom_field>Mohammad Ali Akbari</custom_field>
```

This result comes from `$endpoint_user->custom_field = 'Mohammad Ali Akbari';` in `_endpoint_user_resource_retrieve`